# what is the right way to run a pytorch model bin

Tags: pytorch

I’m new to pytorch. I see lots of tutorials that focus on how to use the API to train, but my question is, once I have a trained model, i have this 3 files :

```
pytorch_model.bin 
config.json
preprocessor_config.json
```

my question is how i load a model and test some Picture on him

```
train_results = trainer.train()
```

trainer.save_model()

Comment: If you have a folder containing `.bin` file, you can load the model using `model = <MODEL_NAME>.from_pretrained("path/to/saved/folder")`.